# Firebase analytics debug in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase-analytics

I want to pass my QA a build with debug mode to see action live in Firebase debugView screen.
It worked when added the "-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled" into the scheme and ran the app directly from Xcode, but now I want to check the events directly from my development device so that's how the QA is checking it.

I put this line code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

> NSMutableArray *newArguments = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments]];
>   [newArguments addObject:@"-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled"];
>   [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] setValue:[newArguments copy] forKey:@"arguments"];

After this lines, I have the following:

> ```
> // [START configure_firebase]
> [FIRApp configure];
> // [END configure_firebase]
> ```

```
// [START set_messaging_delegate]
[FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;
// [END set_messaging_delegate]
```

And it still don't work for me.

What m I missing here?

FYI, i launched the app instance throw xcode, i didn't have build yet. i want to check it b4 make a build.